# Express/Morgan not reporting Javascript fatal errors

Tags: express, morgan

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var logger = require('morgan');

var indexRouter = require('./routes/index');

var app = express();

app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

app.use('/', indexRouter);

module.exports = app;
```

I have tried using different morgan identifiers than just "dev", like "common". However, JavaScript errors inside of the express application are not getting reported to the console and the route just returns an error code, like 400 or so.

error.js

```
module.exports.removeDuplicates = function(x) {
    y = [];
    for(var i=0; i<x.length; i++) {
        if(!y.includes(x[i]))
            y.push(x[i]);
    }
    thisisanerror
    return y;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I read "Morgan" and "logger", and I thought that I can use Morgan to log everything.

However Morgan ist just an HTTP logger. It only logs the HTTP methods, paths, params, response time, etc.

You will need something like log4js: https://www.npmjs.com/package/log4js